# Shutdown embedded Jetty in Spring-Boot Application with Apache CXF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cxf

In a Spring-Boot Application I register an Apache-CXF SOAP Service like this:

```
  @Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
  org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server server(MyService myService) {
    JaxWsServerFactoryBean svrFactory = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
    svrFactory.setServiceClass(MyService.class);
    svrFactory.setAddress("http://0.0.0.0:4711/MyService");
    svrFactory.setServiceBean(myService);
    svrFactory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    svrFactory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    return svrFactory.create();
  }
```

It may happen at other places of my spring configuration, that the context can not be initialized succesfully (Application startup failed) and the application shutdown is initiated.

Unfortunately the sever bean, which is already created, stays alive and prevents the application from shutting down completely. I thought that `destroyMethod = "destroy"` would do the trick, but that only destroys the webapp/SOAP endpoint (resultig in HTTP ERROR 404) but the embedded jetty is still running.

Do I have any chance to configure the Spring Context in a way that prevents the embedded Jetty from staying alive when the Spring Context initialization failes at some point?

Comment: Maybe, it may comes from the fact that your are instantiating a CXF-server as part of the spring's application configuration. Did you try to register your CXF-servlet using a ServletRegistrationBean instead?

Comment: I did not try the ServletRegistrationBean because my approach is the documented way how to [publish the service](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/a-simple-jax-ws-service.html). But I will have a look - thanks.